# Indenting lines using recursion in C

Tags: c, recursion

I'm new to C, and I'm trying to write a function which indents lines using recursion. I've been trying to think of a way to do it, but I can't figure it out.

The text should look like this:

```
This is a text
    This is a text
        This is a text
```

Comment: Why do you need to do it with recursion?  Also, is there a question here?

Comment: WHY do you want recursion? This could possibly be implemented without it.

Comment: Pass the current indentation level as a parameter, and have the function add an appropriate amount to get its indentation level.

Comment: I'm learning recursion. This is a part of a program that I have to write using recursion.

Comment: Oh...  maybe you should have mentioned the "*I* have to write" bit earlier, and you wouldn't end up with code that you *didn't* write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass an indent level into your recursive function and increase it by one when you make a recursive call.

```
void indent( const char * text, int level, int limit )
{
    if( level >= limit ) return;
    printf( "%*s%s\n", level * 4, "", text );
    indent( text, level + 1, limit );
}
```

Invoke as:

```
indent( "This is a text", 0, 3 );
```